# Help in decompiling an SWF

Tags: security, flash, obfuscation, decompiling

Some time ago, me and my friend started working on a Flex project...
Now it's almost finished, we are working on protection:
my friend implemented a sort of encryption in the swf, so all the decompilers (we've tried) read the file as a "flash" app, and not "flex", so it's not possible to get the original sources etc...
But (oh, yes, there is a "but")... The decompilers we've tried (Trilli, Sothink etc) have some "special" features: one of these is that they automatically can check if swfs were made in flex or in flash (so our encrypted files always seems written in flash)... 
But we would also like to check if this sort of protection works on "manual" decompilers (manually set flash or flex decompiling), so: some of you maybe know some decompilers that can "force parsing" in flex, or maybe some "only-flex" decompilers?
Thanks in advance

Comment: roll-your-own encryption: every cracker's dream. I think what your friend implemented is called "obfuscation."

Comment: Yeah, it's an obuscation xD.. But is there any way to get the original sources (in flex), edit them and then recompiling? (I don't need to edit the content of the app, I only need to edit two or threed strings to check if it's really possibile for crackers to do it without deobfuscating the file)

Comment: What do you think will the memory will look like, once your SWF is executing normally?

Answer (score 0):

@Antonius Magnae

There is no short answer.

**Flash vs. Flex Decompilation Comparison:**

**Differences:**

1. Flash is weaker than Flex, i.e. It is more vulnerable to be decompiled, part of this because commercial decompiling programs were designed to return the SWF to a Flash files not Flex project. Later Flex support was added and it is not that powerful yet.
2. Flex code can be decompiled but most often recompiling it will generate compiling errors.

**Similarities:**

1. Both Flash and Flex RIAs can be broken EASILY, since they depend on the SWF.

You have to know that SWF cracking is (no not easy) possible, check this question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159586/removing-a-watermark-from-an-swf-file)

In this question (which you'll notice I've accepted my own answer) I did remove the water mark I've put in Flash, what I want to tell you finally that the same thing could be done if the file was a Flex-programmed file but as we all know what matters is code, crackers can get all your code whether you use Flash or Flex but it is harder in Flex to get it to work by recompilation.