# Removing a Watermark from an SWF file

Tags: flash

I have an SWF file which I water-marked.

and then, I thought of removing the watermark from the SWF file by modifying its raw data on disk.

And since SWF is an open standard, I've taken a look at SWF Flash Player 10 Specs from Adobe.

My watermark is a movieclip object which is loaded in the first frame. but till now I'm not able to remove it.

I am trying to inspect the tag (DefineSprite) which is coded in Hex as (3F 09) which is converted to (09 3F) because of the little endian.

Or there is a different approach, which is to remove the control tag (PlaceObject2) which I couldn't find in the same file HEX dump.

P.S: Yes, I've decompressed the file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thorough studying and analysis of the head-ache-y Adobe documents I've got it done.

I had to remove 2 tags with a size of about (650) bytes including image data and so, reducing file size also (another benefit).

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Could you share the technique you used ? It would be helpful for community members who read your question and want to achieve the same. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it is not a technique per se, and after you've done something you look back and say 'easy'. I kept looking for tags matches in the file till I find about 180 of them, and I chose the largest one since it is the one that carries the image data and removed that from the file, and it was removed leaving no trace. Apparently I want to apply more robust security practices, I think we need opinions here if I can remove my own security from the other side, is it too weak or it is just that I am the one who created the watermark (security barrier here) and it is normal to be removed by me?

Answer (score 0):

Loaded dynamically? From where? Can't you change the URL and load something else instead? (Empty SWF)

**UPDATE**

There is one more option - **cross-movie scripting** - but it depends on how you will be using the SWF. You can create a "loader.swf" that will load your "watermarked.swf" and if they reside on the same domain you can load it to the loader's own [ApplicationDomain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html). Then you can access and traverse the watermarked's display list, search for the watermark and remove it.

Comment: No dainel, I have the file on disk, decompressed (not decompiled). The watermark is included within the file (in the library), it is not loaded from a domain or something, it is simply loaded from the SWF file itself and added to the stage in the 1st frame. Have you guys worked with SWF file structure on this low-level?

Comment: Again No, it is on the local library of the SWF. That's what I'm trying to do, accessing the display list and modify it but it is so confusing when you dive in that HEX sea. I am trying to manipulate a smaller file sizes then I'll try to miss with the large one.

Comment: nope you don't understand me, I don't mean to modify the swf file, I mean traverse the display list programmatically at runtime. I don't know what's your AS3 understanding, do you want more help on this?

Comment: Aha interesting, I am good at AS3 and its OOP, Yes I want help about that please, what I think you meant is traversing the display list at run-time and dump that from Flash Player to the disk, right?

Comment: ok then, do you know where the watermark is located on the screen (what's his parent) and what's his name? If yes then it should not be a problem. I have to continue in the question editor...

Answer (score 0):

By decompressed do you mean decompiled? If not, by using some of the decompilers available like the [sothink decompiler](http://www.sothink.com/product/flashdecompiler/?gclid=CODP0_eKm6UCFQkw3godtk3cHQ) you can get the assets from the swf file. By the way, if you do not have copyright to this swf what you want to do might be in violation of copyright laws. Instead, you should ask the author of the swf...

Comment: No, by decompressed I mean that the zLib part of the file is decompressed. I don't want to use decompilers, I own the file and I know what it contains. But, you can say I'm doing some sort of security test over my watermark. It is a good thing that I'm not able to remove it, but I'm not that expert.

Comment: Ok, no I do not know the bytecodes of swf files so I can not help you there. However I can assure you that theoretically it is "hackable", if that is what you are asking.

Comment: I'm asking about the (How?) more on the (Can it be done?) because I know it can. Thanks though.